# Removing anything after first newline in SQL Server select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column 'Name' that contains newlines. We want to remove the newline as well as anything after the first instance of a newline.

The first step I did was replacing a newline with an empty string and it worked:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Then, I tried replacing any newline with a '----' instead so I can use it with charindex() and only get anything left of it:

```
LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '----'), CHAR(10), '----'), CHARINDEX('----',REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '----'), CHAR(10), '----'))-1)
```

This gives an error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." which is to be expected because not all the names have a newline.

To account for those that dont have a new line I used substring() and case() wherein if it has no newline it will the substring length of the original else it will use charindex('----',...) instead.

```
  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '----'), CHAR(10), '----'),1,
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('----',REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '----'), CHAR(10), '----')) = 0 THEN LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '----'), CHAR(10), '----'))
  ELSE CHARINDEX('----',REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '----'), CHAR(10), '----'))-1 END)
```

Is there a more intuitive way of going about this where I don't have to replace the newlines with a string using that string as a reference point and using the newlines as a reference point instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't handling values that *don't* have a carriage return. As a result the position returned by `CHARINDEX` would be `0`, and you can't have the -1 left most characters.

Add a carriage return to the end of your string, and then get the `CHARINDEX`:

```sql
LEFT(YourColumn, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), YourColumn + CHAR(13))
```

Comment: How do I account for when the newline is CHAR(10)? I tried doing a nested Left but there are still some newlines showing up: LEFT(LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), Name + CHAR(10))), CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), Name + CHAR(10))) + CHAR(13)))

Comment: `REPLACE` the carriage returns with a new line first @googlesheettest , and look for new lines instead.